# Cannot (again) assign correct value to signed short

Tags: c++

Why this gives zero as an output? I suspect some compiler work in it but why?

```
  signed int sint_ = numeric_limits<signed int>::min() << '\n';  
    cout << "signed int: " << sint_ << '\n';
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is because of the accidental `<< '\n'` on the first line. Its effect is to left shift the bits of the minimum value by 13 positions (13 being the character code of `\n`). Since the bit pattern of the most negative value is `1000...0`, the result becomes 0.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: Copy/paste makes blind (I assume you originally had all of this on one line) - I've certainly done similar things myself ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
signed int sint_ = numeric_limits<signed int>::min() << '\n';
```

What is this `\n` at the end?

Is this not what you want:

```
signed int sint_ = numeric_limits<signed int>::min();
```

?

Demo : http://ideone.com/aOXGH

Comment: @Alexander: How can you say `\n` is not the problem? Its part of the problem. One can say that the problem is not `shift operator` either, because if you replace `<<\n` with `<< 0`, the code will work as expected, even though shift operator is still there.